# How does one configure Unity to resolve the correct HttpControllerContext instance for an ASP.NET Web API application?

Tags: c#-4.0, unity-container, asp.net-web-api

Suppose I have a [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) controller that uses a service, which in turn depends on HttpControllerContext to perform some processing.

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController {

  IMyService _service;

  MyApiController(IMyService service) {
    _service = service;
  }

  public void Post(Resource resource) {
     _service.Process(resource);
  }
}

public interface IMyService {
  void Process(Resource resource);
}

public class MyService : IMyService {
  HttpControllerContext _controllerContext;

  MyService(HttpControllerContext controllerContext) {
    _controllerContext = controllerContext;
  }

  public void Process(Resource resource) {
     // use _controllerContext and process resource
  }
}
```

How does one configure [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/) to inject an instance of HttpControllerContext when MyService is created?  I am unable to find a way to get the HttpControllerContext used by the controller to be "injected" into the instance of MyService so it can use it.

Comment: just re-read your question :)

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at, there is no implicit answer in my question. I am unable to find a way to get the HttpControllerContext used by the controller to be "injected" into the instance of "MyService" so it can use it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at [Mark Seemann's post on how to wire HttpControllerContext with Castle Windsor](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/04/19/WiringHttpControllerContextWithCastleWindsor.aspx). Unity should work similar.

Comment: Sadly, no longer works in the RTM: `IHttpControllerActivator.Create` doesn't accept `HttpControllerContext` as an argument any more.